# Bootstrap table with javascript using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a table to display properly using the following code. The problem is that the `</tbody>` and `</table>` tags are being applied before the for loop enters the data into the table. The table head displays fine and the data displays fine as well, just not in the table.  What am I doing wrong? I tried moving the last line into the loop with in if statement but the same happens.

```
    $.getJSON("adriver.php?type=get", function(data, status){
    document.getElementById("aRightContent").innerHTML =
            "<table class='table table-hover'>" +
            "<thead>" +
            "<tr>" +
                "<th><i class='fa fa-check-square'></iclass></th>" +
                "<th>ID</th>" +
                "<th>Firstname</th>" +
                "<th>Lastname</th>" +
                "<th>UserName</th>" +
            "</tr>" +
            "</thead>" +
            "<tbody>";

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("aRightContent").innerHTML +=
                "<tr>" +
                    "<td><input type='radio' name='selectedDriver' value='" + data[i].dID + "'></td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].dID + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].dFirstName + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].dLastName + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].dUsername + "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("aRightContent").innerHTML += "</tbody></table>";
});
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: can't write to the dom as if it is a text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add partial `<table>` and `</table>` using the `innerHTML`, as the browser tends to fill it out for you. Best way I would suggest is to build the whole HTML and then append.

So you should have something like:

```
finalHTML = "<table class='table table-hover'>" +
        "<thead>" +
        "<tr>" +
            "<th><i class='fa fa-check-square'></iclass></th>" +
            "<th>ID</th>" +
            "<th>Firstname</th>" +
            "<th>Lastname</th>" +
            "<th>UserName</th>" +
        "</tr>"
        "</thead>" +
        "<tbody>";
finalHTML += "..."  // Other code.
```

Also, since you are using jQuery, use the same components. Instead of `document.getElementById("aRightContent").innerHTML`, use:

```
$("#aRightContent").html()
```

Comment: Works great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just write the whole thing in a string:

```
var htmlString = "<table class='table table-hover'>" +
        "<thead>" +
        "<tr>" +
            "<th><i class='fa fa-check-square'></iclass></th>" +
            "<th>ID</th>" +
            "<th>Firstname</th>" +
            "<th>Lastname</th>" +
            "<th>UserName</th>" +
        "</tr>"
        "</thead>" +
        "<tbody>";
```

etc...

And use then asign to `innerHTML = htmlString` at the end.

## Reason

You shouldn't assign to `document.getElementById("aRightContent").innerHTML` an incomplete piece of HTML code.